# Content is bigger that flexbox container on mobile browsers

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I wrote small site [dlang.ru](http://dlang.ru/book). It's working fine on desktop, but I on mobile browsers content of book page is breaking container and I can't understand what's wrong.

I tried to set `min-width` to 100% and to `100vw` but without any result.

Here is site css:

```
/* Mobile View */
@media (max-width: 1080px) {  
    .MainContainer {
      background-color: #f7f5f0;
      margin-left: 0%;
      margin-right: 0%;
      min-height: 100vh;
      min-width: 100vw;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
    }
  }
```

[image]

upd: I found the reason of issue. It's too long string:
`std.getopt.GetOptException@C:\D\dmd2\windows\bin\..\..\src\phobos\std\getopt.d(727): Required option password|p was not supplied`

Is it's possible to add line wrapping in code block?

Comment: It’s the `code` blocks you have further down the page, those do not break their content as you intended ...

Comment: How can I fix it?

Comment: Well setting a `max-width: 100%` for the first `div` child of your `.Middle` element, and adding `overflow-wrap: break-word` for the `code` elements seems to fix the page width issue ... but whether the content of those code blocks then still makes sense, might be another question. Especially those where you used “ASCII art” to create lines pointing to specific function parameters etc. get a bit messed up by that of course ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `flex-direction: row` to `flex-direction: column` for `.Middle`.

This will work because flex container by default stretch flex items along the cross axis (i.e. due to default `align-items: stretch` value).

Also you can remove redundant `div` wrapper inside `.Middle` and move content directly to `.Middle`.

Comment: I can't remove redundant `div` because I use `pug` template and some  vue.js function in it for loading page content by `post` request. Here is my pug: `div(v-html='all_content')` I can't move it to level up.

Comment: @user1432751 OK, then add `width: 100%` for this block if you can't remove it.

Comment: Hm, I did what you say about changing row to column, and it's helped. Why? Even without `width: 100%`

Comment: @user1432751 Updated answer.